# 13.04 No sound while running applications as separate user

Tags: sound, 13.04, ssh, pulseaudio, multiseat

Firstly I have to say I'm really enjoying Ubuntu 13.04, many changes seem subtle but overall it seems to be a much improved experience over 12.10. Most notably the snappy gui responsivity is awesome.
There's actually not a whole lot I can complain about so far, and that's an unusual experience for me with Linux! 
But my major grievance at the moment, is having recently upgraded to Raring, I've noticed that:

"sudo su testuseraccount", then running any application, results in that application running without audio. :O(
Where as doing the same on Lubuntu 12.10 (although it didn't work on my Ubuntu 12.10 livecd session) the sound is fine.

I imagine if there's no workaround for this, it will totally kill any chance of using Raring Ringtail as a multiseat OS. Also it means applications that won't run at all without audio, won't run when they're running on a secondary login.

I had a look posts regarding simultaneous multi user access to pulse audio, but it's all double Dutch to me, and I suspect most of it wasn't relevant to this particular situation.

So can anyone tell me if there's anything that can be done to get back sound on secondary user sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like only users belonging to the *audio* group can use audio devices after switching user accounts with `su`. So you have to do this:

```
sudo usermod -G audio -a account
```

(replace account with the account you want to use audio with)

It will then work for new sessions started after adding the user to the audio group.